# Windows phone 8.1 network connectivity

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

When in star bucks or other additional user action required WiFi places, the phone is usually connected to the WiFi and but not the network. Usually a web browser pops up asking for credentials or accept terms and conditions.

In Windows phone 8.1 are there any API's to check if the phone is connected to network? I know there are APIs to check for internet profiles. But how do you actually know if the network is available ?

This is an edge case scenario where the user might close the browser without even accepting the terms and conditions. This time the WiFi is still connected.

Any work arounds ?

Comment: Is there really a point in knowing whether the user has internet connectivity? Even if you handle this corner case, you always have to wrap your network calls in try/catch blocks because the user may lose network at any moment. So... Detecting this case sounds like a lot of pain for almost no reward

Comment: Its a case that has to be considered in any phone app that uses the network.